# file to dictionary:value is a dictionary where the key is repeated

Tags: python, file, dictionary, key

I open a file which contains this:

```
TransactionNo   Date        CustomerId      PurchasePairs
-------------   ----        ----------      -------------
1               09-04-2014  barakobama      potatoes:2.67,sugar:1.98,cereal:5.99,crisps:1.09
2               11-04-2014  barakobama      parsley:0.76,cereal:3.22
3               11-04-2014  vladimirputin   bread:0.66,milk:2.87,parsley:1.33
```

and i want output dictionary like this:

```
{'milk': {'vladimirputin': 2.87}, 'cereal': {'barakobama': 9.21},
'bread': {'vladimirputin': 0.66}, 'potatoes': {'barakobama': 2.67}, 
'sugar': {'barakobama': 1.98}, 'parsley': {'vladimirputin': 1.33,
```

I have done this:

```
 C={}
file=open(fileNameStr,'r')


for line in file:
    if line[0].isdigit():
        fields = line.split()
```

Comment: Why have you come back with even less code than [your previous "attempt"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240008/how-can-i-turn-a-file-into-dictionary)?

Comment: its the same code,its just more clear now

Comment: You have an answer already, why this new question? Why haven't you used that answer, or even attempted to modify it?

Comment: cause i dont get the output i want

Comment: So modify the code for the output you want, or at least *attempt to do so*. If the previous question was wrong, *edit it*. If the answer was wrong, *comment on it*. I note you have another, [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220124/update-dictionary-by-incrementing) whose answers you've also ignored, so why should anyone bother to answer this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
c = {}
f = open(fileNameStr)
for line in f:
    if not line[0].isdigit(): continue
    transactionNo, _date, customerId, purchasePairs = line.split()
    for pair in purchasePairs.split(','):
        productName, price = pair.split(':')
        if productName in c:
            c[productName][customerId] = float(price)
        else:
            c[productName] = {customerId: float(price)}
```

you have to deal with one contition: that is a customer buy same thing more than one times.
hope this code will help.

Comment: just a difference at the output 'cereal': {'barakobama': 9.21}

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

final_products = dict()

file_name = "myfile"
try:
    # it's better not to use reserved name like 'file'
    # fhd, for example, is better
    # you might want to remove encoding='utf-8' depending on your python version (2 or 3) :
    fhd = open(file_name, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') 
except:
    # here we cannot read the file
    raise
else:
    # ok, file is opened
    for line in fhd:
        if line[0].isdigit():
            fields = line.split()
            # there should be exactly 4 fields
            if len(fields) == 4:
                products      = fields[3].split(',')
                consumer      = fields[2]
                for p in products:
                    product_details = p.split(':')
                    if len(product_details) == 2:
                        product_name     = product_details[0]
                        product_quantity = float(product_details[1])
                        # first we check if the product is in the dict 
                        # if not we add it
                        if product_name not in final_products.keys():
                            final_products[product_name] = dict()
                        # does the consumer already bought this product ?
                        if consumer not in final_products[product_name].keys():
                            final_products[product_name][consumer] = 0.0
                        # finaly we add the quantity bought by the consumer
                        final_products[product_name][consumer] += product_quantity
    # close the file
    fhd.close

print(final_products)
```

This prints :

```
{'cereal': {'barakobama': 9.21}, 'potatoes': {'barakobama': 2.67}, 'parsley': {'vladimirputin': 1.33, 'barakobama': 0.76}, 'sugar': {'barakobama': 1.98}, 'crisps': {'barakobama': 1.09}, 'milk': {'vladimirputin': 2.87}, 'bread': {'vladimirputin': 0.66}}
```